# Short não reconhece data inteira

Tags: javascript, aplicação-web

Olá, como eu faço para que o short reconheça todo o objeto

```
{
  "Dir": "Sd:/",
  "List": [
    {
      "Tipo": "P.O.S.-",
      "Data": "11/10/2017",
      "Hora": "23:58",
      "Size": "0",
      "Nome": "Arquivo1"
    },
    {
      "Tipo": "P.-.-.-",
      "Data": "12/05/2017",
      "Hora": "23:57",
      "Size": "0",
      "Nome": "Arquivo2"
    },
    {
      "Tipo": "P.-.-.A",
      "Data": "14/10/2017",
      "Hora": "23:57",
      "Size": "0",
      "Nome": "Arquivo3"
    },
    {
      "Tipo": "P.-.-.-",
      "Data": "16/12/2017",
      "Hora": "23:57",
      "Size": "0",
      "Nome": "Arquivo4"
    },
    {
      "Tipo": "P.-.-.-",
      "Data": "29/09/2017",
      "Hora": "23:57",
      "Size": "0",
      "Nome": "Arquivo5"
    }
  ],
  "NArq": "0",
  "NPast": "5"
}
```

Quero organizar o objeto "Data" por ordem de ultima modificação.

```
var a = a.Data.toLowerCase();
var b = b.Data.toLowerCase();
return a < b ? -1 : a > b ? 1 : 0;
```

Ele só detecta o primeiro numero, mas o resto não :/

Comment: Podes explicar melhor _"só detecta o primeiro numero"_ e _"toda a variável"_? estás a tentar fazer `.sort()` por datas?

Comment: Ele não detecta o mês, somente o primeiro digito. Quero organizar uma lista com datas "08/11/2017" em ordem de ultima modificação

Comment: E esse `a.Data` é um objeto `Date` ou uma string no formato `dd/mm/aaaa/`?

Comment: Vou editar a pergunta para ficar melhor

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Para organizar uma array de *Date* tens de usar *timestamps* e não a versão de texto de uma data. Usa o `.getTime()` e já vai funcionar como queres. Vais ter de converter essa `Data` e `Hora` num objeto `Date` único antes de fazer a conversão para *timestamp*.

Exemplo:

```js
function converterData(data, hora) {
  var partes = data.split('/').reverse().map(Number);
  partes[1]++;
  var hm = hora.split(':').map(Number);

  return new Date(partes[0], partes[1], partes[2], hm[0], hm[1]).getTime();
}

function ordenarDatas(a, b) {
  a = converterData(a.Data, a.Hora);
  b = converterData(b.Data, b.Hora);
  return a < b ? -1 : a > b ? 1 : 0;
}

var desordenado = {
  "Dir": "Sd:/",
  "List": [{
      "Tipo": "P.O.S.-",
      "Data": "29/09/2017",
      "Hora": "23:58",
      "Size": "0",
      "Nome": "Arquivo1"
    },
    {
      "Tipo": "P.-.-.-",
      "Data": "29/09/2037", // <-- 2037!
      "Hora": "23:57",
      "Size": "0",
      "Nome": "Arquivo2"
    },
    {
      "Tipo": "P.-.-.A",
      "Data": "29/09/1997", // <-- 1997
      "Hora": "23:57",
      "Size": "0",
      "Nome": "Arquivo3"
    },
    {
      "Tipo": "P.-.-.-",
      "Data": "29/09/2017",
      "Hora": "23:59",
      "Size": "0",
      "Nome": "Arquivo4"
    },
    {
      "Tipo": "P.-.-.-",
      "Data": "29/09/2017",
      "Hora": "23:57",
      "Size": "0",
      "Nome": "Arquivo5"
    }
  ],
  "NArq": "0",
  "NPast": "5"
}

var ordenado = desordenado.List.sort(ordenarDatas);
console.log(ordenado);
```

Comment: Obrigado, resolveu o problema :)

Comment: Obrigado pelo feedback! Votos de usuários com menos de 15 de reputação reputação são registrados, mas não mudam a pontuação mostrada no post.

Comment: @PlanetWar às vezes pode demorar um pouco até mudar a pontuação.